# Ef Core: How to put migrations for sveral different dbContexts to one assembly?

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2019, ef-core-2.2

In my application I have two different dbContexts (in two different assemblies) e.g. DeliveriesDbContext and AuthenticationDbContext but want to put migrations to one command line tool.

So I have created the command line app and trying to generate Migrations for both contexts.

I can specify the Migrations custom folder name:

```
Add-Migration Intitial -OutputDir "DeliveriesDbContextMigrations"
```

But how to specify which context to put to which folder?

Answer (score 0):

`Add-Migration` has a parameter named `-Context`, it is basically used for migrations with multiple providers, but in the case you have mentioned it works.

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context MyDbContextOne -OutputDir Migrations\SqlServerMigrationsOne

Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context MyDbContextTwo -OutputDir Migrations\SqlServerMigrationsTwo
```

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/providers)